LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IMAGE::BuildImage
I have a Visual Studio C++ 2017 solution.
The solution has two projects:

my_cpp_project
my_cpp_project_unit_test

I am getting the following error while building the solution:

1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: my_cpp_project, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>my_cpp_project.cpp
1>my_cpp_project.vcxproj -> C:\git\my_cpp_project_directory\x64\Debug\my_cpp_project.exe
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: my_cpp_project_unit_test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>pch.cpp
2>test_autocorrelations.cpp
2>test_energy.cpp
2>Generating Code...
2>   Creating library C:\git\my_cpp_project_directory\x64\Debug\my_cpp_project_unit_test.lib and object C:\git\my_cpp_project_directory\x64\Debug\my_cpp_project_unit_test.exp
2>
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IMAGE::BuildImage
2>
2>  Version 14.16.27051.0
2>
2>  ExceptionCode            = C0000005
2>  ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
2>  ExceptionAddress         = 5829282E (58290000) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\VCRUNTIME140.dll"
2>  NumberParameters         = 00000002
2>  ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000001
2>  ExceptionInformation[ 1] = FFBA0000
2>
2>CONTEXT:
2>  Eax    = 00AF5488  Esp    = 003AECA8
2>  Ebx    = 00AF5408  Ebp    = 003AECD4
2>  Ecx    = 00000080  Esi    = 00AF5408
2>  Edx    = 00000080  Edi    = FFBA0000
2>  Eip    = 5829282E  EFlags = 00010247
2>  SegCs  = 00000023  SegDs  = 0000002B
2>  SegSs  = 0000002B  SegEs  = 0000002B
2>  SegFs  = 00000053  SegGs  = 0000002B
2>  Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
2>  Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
2>  Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000
2>Done building project "my_cpp_project_unit_test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========


How can I resolve this?

So far I have tried:

Disable Precompiled Headers (PCH)
a. Right-click on your project (e.g., surpass_cpp_copy_unit_test) and select Properties.
b. Under C/C++ > Precompiled Headers, change Precompiled Header to Not Using Precompiled Headers.
c. Try rebuilding the solution after this change.

Adjust Linker Settings
a. Open your project properties.
b. Navigate to Linker > Advanced and try changing the Image Has Safe Exception Handlers to No.
c. Alternatively, set the Link Time Code Generation option to Disabled under Linker > Optimization.

Reinstall Toolchain


Those actions didn't resolve the issue.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/lnk1000-internal-error-during-imagebuildimage-on-d/789991 seems relevant, says you need to update your toolchain/operating system

@AhmedAEK, I am using toolchain v141. I cannot upgrade further.

try updating your operating system then, as written in that linked thread

@AhmedAEK, That is also not possible: I am using Lenovo T430 Thinkpad with Win10. The machine is too weak to run Win11.

how about not using MSVC and using msys2 with mingw or clang, clang even has an msvc-compatible front-end so you don't have to use MSVC compiler and linker but still use visual studio, you can download clang without msys2, it is just easier to use msys2 as a package manager

note that you can update windows 10 without converting to windows 11 (i am still running windows 10 with updates on a few machines)

Try turning off incremental linking, then clean the project and force a full rebuild.

Also consider using the V141 toolchain in VS2022.

I have tried various ways to resolve the MSTest-related issue but ultimately failed.
So, I have resolved the issue in an indirect way.

I have replaced the MStest project with a Google Test project.
I have opened each *.vcxproj file with notepad++
a. replaced 10.0.XXXX in <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.XXXX</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion> with 8.1.
b. replaced v142 in <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset> with v141

Now, everything is working fine.
